# Show layer name in attribute table in print composer?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, print-composer

When adding attribute tables in the print composers it is not possible to distinguish between various tables from various layers; each table is generic and does not indicate which layer the table is from.
Is there a simple way to add an additional header or even a caption to indicate the source layer?

Answer (score 2):

Not as far as I know. I think it will be most direct to add a text/label box above each of the tables, where you manually enter the layer name.

Comment: You could merge the layers and hide the non-wanted objects in map by Field Calculator, defined by attribute parameters.